# Jasmine unit test failing?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I've installed the Jasmine node module and set up a test function in `test.js` with corresponding specs file `testSpec.js`.

test.js:

```
var Test = function () {
    var testFunction = function () {
        return 'test worked';
    }
    return{
        testFunction:testFunction
    }
}

module.exports = Test();
```

testSpec.js:

```
var Test = require('../src/js/test');

describe("Test Function", function () {
    it("returns 'test worked'", function () {
        expect(Test.testFunction().toEqual('test worked'));
    });
});
```

When I run the test I receive the following error:

```
Message:
  TypeError: Test.testFunction(...).toEqual is not a function
Stack:
  TypeError: Test.testFunction(...).toEqual is not a function
```

Hard-coding the result `'test worked'`, I receive no errors and the test passes as expected.

What am I missing?

Comment: @T4rk1n see edit, I added those in when I was trouble-shooting. I receive the same errors when removed.

Comment: it's not toEqual it's toBe

Comment: @T4rk1n I get the same error regardless of matcher.

Comment: Try this `expect(Test.testFunction()).toBe('test worked')`

Comment: @T4rk1n ha, that was it! My parenthesis were bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parenthesis in the wrong place for `expect` - here you go:

```
describe("Test Function", function () {
    it("returns 'test worked'", function () {
        expect(Test.testFunction()).toEqual('test worked');
    });
});
```

edit: for clarity - the error you received is because you were chaining `toEqual` off of your function call rather than the encapsulating `expect`.

Comment: Yea, I definitely see that now, so obvious.